# Updating sent SMS in default app thread

Tags: android, android-intent, smsmanager

I have developed an app in which I send an SMS upon a certain event. I have experimented with the
following two methods:

**Method 1:**

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                     sms.sendTextMessage(srcNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

**Method 2:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "sms:" + srcNumber)); 
                    intent.putExtra( "sms_body", message ); 
                    startActivity(intent);
```

My requirements are:

1) The SMS should be sent without opening the phone's default SMS app.

2) The sent SMS should appear in the message thread in the default message app.

**Method 1** satisfies requirement 1 and **Method 2** satisfies requirement 2. Is there any way to satisfy **both** my requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                     sms.sendTextMessage(srcNumber, null, message, null, null);


ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", srcNumber);
values.put("body", message);
getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
```

This should solve it.

NOTE: This requires [android.permission.WRITE_SMS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_SMS) permission